# Pandas Timestamp: What type is this?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with a parsed time stamp.  What type is this? I have tried matching against it with the following rules:

```
dtype_dbg = df[col].dtype # debugger shows it as 'datetime64[ns]'
if isinstance(df[col].dtype,np.datetime64) # no luck
if isinstance(df[col].dtype,pd.Timestamp)  # ditto
if isinstance(df[col].dtype,[all other timestamps I could think of]) # nothing
```

How does one match against the timestamp dtype in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `datetime64[ns]` is a `'<M8[ns]'` numpy type, so you can just compare the `dtype`s:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'col': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02']})
df.col = pd.to_datetime(df.col)
df.info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
#Data columns (total 1 columns):
#col    2 non-null datetime64[ns]
#dtypes: datetime64[ns](1)
#memory usage: 144.0 bytes

df[col].dtype == np.dtype('<M8[ns]')
#True
```

You can also (or maybe should better) use pandas built-in [`api.types.is_...` functions](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/general_utility_functions.html#dtype-introspection):

```
pd.api.types.is_datetime64_ns_dtype(df[col])
#True
```

Your comparisons `isinstance(df[col].dtype, ...)` don't work, as you compare *the type of `dtype`* (which is `numpy.dype` of course) with other data dtypes, which will naturally fail for any data type.